# C# Convert To Decimal String Value like 0.33

Tags: c#, decimal, type-conversion

How to convert this `string` to `decimal` 0.55  exactly.
`Decimal.parse("0,55")`
I need to get exact value excluding leading zeroes.

Comment: The value of a `decimal` doesn't know how many leading zeroes there are. 00000.55 and .55 are the same value. (Trailing zeroes are a different matter.) If you just want to make sure that when you convert *back to a string* there's at least one digit before the decimal point, use a custom format.

Comment: What is the use of leading zero if the calcul works without it?

Comment: I'm guessing the problem is that the framework doesn't recognize the comma as a decimal separator?

Comment: Hmm,  I need this value exactly converted for multiplying. I am getting string "0.55"  I need to convert to decimal and multiply with integer so result need to be correct.

Comment: Convert.ToDouble(Regex.Match("0,55", 
                   @"\d+").Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

Comment: So the real problem is that the result of multiplying a `decimal` with an `ìnteger` is of type `integer`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should fix your problem (if I understand the problem, that is):

```
var number = decimal.Parse("0,55".Replace(',', '.'), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

**EDIT**

Not every culture uses the point (`.`) symbol as the decimal separator. If you don't specify a format provider, the framework defaults to the current culture. I'm guessing that in this particular case, the `decimal.Parse()` method was interpreting `"0,55"` as decimal `55.0`.

Comment: Can you add explanation of _why_ culture is important while parsing?

Comment: Steven answered correct. This is what I need. Thank you all guys ...